# How to create a custom button in Windows Explorer toolbar

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-explorer

I would like to know what is the process to add a custom button to the windows explorer bar programmatically?
It is different in Windows 7 and 8?

Is it possible to do it in C#? Or the best way is C++?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "custom button"?  The windows toolbar just has pinned "shortcuts" to programs/folders etc...

Comment: Buttons like "back" and "forward" in windows explorer toolbar. Something like this: http://media.askvg.com/articles/images/New_Command_Bar_Buttons_Windows_Explorer2.png

Comment: I don't have an answer but I will tell you that typically adding GUI elements to the Windows OS is not an easy process.  You should probably look into WinAPI.  You didn't really specify the "objective" of the program you want to write, or it's purpose so it's hard to go beyond that.  Regarding which language?  I'm sure either have the capability to accomplish the task.

Comment: The basic idea would be to add a button to the toolbar that would call an external program. I know that for commands like Delete it is "easy" using Registry. I would prefer in C# but maybe C++ would be easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buttons are set in the Windows registry, under
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\GUID\TasksItemsSelected` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\GUID\TasksNoItemsSelected`

Use a type of `REG_SZ`, and the data is a `;` separated list of shell command names.

The folder `GUID`s I know are:

- 5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7 -> General
- 5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8 -> Videos
- 7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656 -> Documents
- 94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78 -> Music
- b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239 -> Pictures
- 5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49 -> Other libraries

The tasks you can pick are from the registry key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell`

You can add plain executables to this list by using the `command` subkey, and put the exe command in the data field. Have a look around for examples.

Happy hunting.

Comment: Thanks. It is not possible to add a button that executes a custom application?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You need to add a "command" to the shell command store. You'd end up with a key like `.../CommandStore/shell/MyCommand/command` with a type of `REG_SZ` and a value of `C:\ProgramFiles\MyWonderApp\Wonder.exe`

Comment: @IainBallard Ok I created a registry key with my executable full address as it's **command** value in the following path but supposedly new button doesn't show up in my Windows 7 toolbar: ```HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\MyCommands\command```