# Windows 8,10 File Explorer Ribbon toolbar with custom button

Tags: c++, windows, explorer

is there any way to add a custom button to Windows 8, 10 file explorer?
[Windows File Explorer Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Twsr.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911444/how-to-create-a-custom-button-in-windows-explorer-toolbar

Comment: That is in the old windows 7 explorer, I'm interested in the new explorer since windows 8. Thanks